# Products containing a hyphen or numbers not shown or wrong relevance

Tags: search

I have an external Apache Solr Server, with Search API and Search API Views.

When we search for ordinary products, they are shown correctly, with the correct descending relevance order.

When we search for a product with the exact name: **"Productx-123W**"
it is showing in this order (with highlighted terms by search function):

- **Productx**-123D
- **Productx**-123S
- **Productx**-123
- **Productx**-**123W**

So the exact product name is only shown on the 4th place, while all other products with no hyphens or `-` in them have the correct displayed order in the results.

It is like the hyphen splits the word in two.

Secondly, I have a product: **Product20001w**
When I look for this search term: "**2000**" nothing is shown. It's like the numbers on the end confuse the server.
When I look for "**2001w**", it shows the right products which have partially this "2001w" in their name.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any custom configuration in your Solr? Can you post it?

Comment: Hi, I just received the config files from "Hosted Apache Solr" https://hostedapachesolr.com/
Here you can download the files: (thanks)
http://www.omegaservers.be/config-apache-solr.zip

Comment: I think Search API Solr module should have a tab where you can see the content of loaded config files as well.

Comment: You are right. there are a bunch of config files there. I didn't change anything there. Can I tweak something to make hyphens in a word be seen as real letters and treated as such ?

Answer (score 1):

It is basically a feature of [Word Delimiter Filter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) to allow matching of words on case-change, alphanumeric boundaries, and non-alphanumeric chars, so when typing "wifi", "wi fi" could match documents containing "Wi-Fi". That is why Product-123A is split to match more products. See: [Intra-Word Delimiters](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyCookbook#IntraWordDelimiters).

So you can either disable *WordDelimiterFilter*, or customize it. For example:

```
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
        protected="protwords.txt"
        generateWordParts="1"
        generateNumberParts="1"
        catenateWords="0"
        catenateNumbers="0"
        catenateAll="0"
        splitOnCaseChange="0"
        preserveOriginal="1"/>
```

Since the second part of your word consist number (e.g. *123W*), you may try to enable `catenateWords` and `catenateNumbers` (set to `1`) in your `schema.xml` file and apply the changes to your hosted Solr server.

You can also provide some customization using`wdftypes.txt` file, see: [SOLR-2059](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2059).

However, if you want to keep the feature as it is (without modifying any Solr config files), you can also consider increasing the score for certain fields, such as titles (e.g. a product name). So your `Productx-123W` phrase after a word split will match higher on documents with partial matches such as `123W` in specific fields.

Related posts:

- [Search with various combinations of space, hyphen, casing and punctuations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29783237/55075)
- [Quering numbers containing hyphens with SOLR WordDelimiterFilterFactory isn't working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12527626/55075)